# For loop through the list unless empty?

Tags: python, for-loop, nonetype

I've been writing a lot of constructs like this the past couple of days:

```
list = get_list()
if list:
    for i in list:
        pass # do something with the list
else:
    pass # do something if the list was empty
```

Lot of junk and I assign the list to a real variable (keeping it in memory longer than needed). Python has simplified a lot of my code up til now... Is there a easy way to do this?

(My understanding is that the `else` in the `for: else:` construct always triggers after it has looped, empty or not - so not what I want)

Comment: I'm not sure anything **could** be easier.  What's wrong with this?  Which line of code would you like to eliminate?

Comment: Well... Ideally I'd like to stop assigning the list to a variable and compact the if/else into part of the for (I know that's unlikely). I could use `with get_list() as list:`, but that pushes things out further

Comment: @Oli: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please *update* your question with additional details.

Comment: What's wrong with iterating over an empty list?

Comment: You probably want to pick a different variable name than 'list' while you're at it.

Comment: May be you could you shed some light on what is it exactly you want to do in case of an empty list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
def do_something(x):
  return x**2

list = []
result = [do_something(x) for x in list if list]
print result        # []

list = [1, 2, 3]
result = [do_something(x) for x in list if list]
print result       # [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: The "if list" at the end is unnecessary and is evaluated for each item, not just once.

Comment: Your comprehensions do not handle list = None

Answer (score 86):

Based on the other answers, I think the cleanest solutions are

```
#Handles None return from get_list
for item in get_list() or []: 
    pass #do something
```

or the comprehension equiv

```
result = [item*item for item in get_list() or []]
```

Comment: this is such a beautiful way to do this check, brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

Slighty more terse is:

```
for i in my_list:
    # got a list
if not my_list:
    # not a list
```

assuming you are not changing the length of the list in the loop.

Edit from Oli: To compensate my worries of memory use, it would want `with`ing:

```
with get_list() as my_list:
    for i in my_list:
        # got a list
    if not my_list:
        # not a list
```

But yes, that's quite a simple way around the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If your actions are **different**, I would do:

```
list_ = get_list() # underscore to keep built-in list
if not list_:
    # do something
for i in list_: #
    # do something for each item
```

If your actions are **similar**, this is more beautiful:

```
for i in list_ or [None]:
   # do something for list item or None
```

or, if you might have `None` as a list element,

```
for i in list_ or [...]:
   # do something for list item or built-in constant Ellipsis
```

Comment: Though the selected answer is great for the OP's question, I appreciate the completeness of this answer regarding how to handle the different scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

```
def do_something_with_maybe_list(maybe_list):
    if maybe_list:
        for x in list:
            do_something(x)
    else:
        do_something_else()

do_something_with_maybe_list(get_list())
```

You could even extract the actions to be done:

```
def do_something_with_maybe_list(maybe_list, process_item, none_action):
    if maybe_list:
        for x in list:
            process_item(x)
    else:
        none_action()

do_something_with_maybe_list(get_list(), do_something, do_something_else)
do_something_with_maybe_list(get_otherlist(), do_other, do_still_other)
```

Edit from Oli: Or go one further:

```
def do_something_with_maybe_list(maybe_list, process_item, none_action):
    if maybe_list:
        return process_list(maybe_list)
    return none_action()

do_something_with_maybe_list(get_list(), do_something, do_something_else)
do_something_with_maybe_list(get_otherlist(), do_other, do_still_other)
```

Comment: Added another layer of down-stripping. The for processing can (and probably aught to) be done externally. And I'll need to return so I can cut out the `else`, guard-style

Answer (score 1):

I think your way is ok in general case, but you may consider this approach:

```
def do_something(item):
   pass # do something with the list

def action_when_empty():
   pass # do something if the list was empty

# and here goes your example
yourlist = get_list() or []
another_list = [do_something(x) for x in yourlist] or action_when_empty()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = None
for i in get_list():
    pass # do something with the list
else:
    if i is None:
        pass # do something if the list was empty
```

Does that help?  Yes I know we are two years away from the need :-)

Comment: This will not work if the last element in get_list() is actually `None`.